# Array handled by unset() and print_r() is either intact or somehow becomes nothing

Tags: php, arrays, unset

The PHP code below randomly selects a color from an array. If the randomly selected color is blue, it returns the array; if the randomly selected color is not blue, it removes that color and recursively executes the function until it randomly selects the blue color and the returns the array.

```php
$reduce_unwanted_colors = function (&$arr) use (&$reduce_unwanted_colors)
{
    $rand_key = array_rand($arr);
    if ($arr[$rand_key] == 'blue')
    {
        return $arr;
    }
    else
    {
        unset($arr[$rand_key]);
        $reduce_unwanted_colors($arr);
    }
};

$arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];
print_r($reduce_unwanted_colors($arr));
```

What is weird is that, the `print_r()` is showing either the intact array or nothing (an empty string maybe?).

I'm not sure whether the `unset()` is accidentally removing all array elements or not. Even if it is, I think the `print_r()` should still show `Array ( )` rather than showing nothing.

What I was expected from the `print_r()` is an array which contains at least an element (the blue color). I cannot figure out what's going on.

Please note that the code is just an example simply for illustration's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing `$arr` by reference, you don't need to return anything from the function; modifying the array in the body is sufficient. This also means you don't have to do anything when you find the `blue` element; just recurse when the current element is not `blue`.

```
$reduce_unwanted_colors = function (&$arr) use (&$reduce_unwanted_colors)
{
    $rand_key = array_rand($arr);
    if ($arr[$rand_key] != 'blue') {
        unset($arr[$rand_key]);
        $reduce_unwanted_colors($arr);
    }
};

$arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];
$reduce_unwanted_colors($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Demo of lots of random output on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/05inn)

Comment: I like this version better

Comment: @FrankerZ I think they're both equally valid. My personal preference (and hence my upvote for your answer) is for functions that explicitly return values rather than modifying parameters.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't return anything from your else statement, it will simply get executed recursively, but not actually return anything. You have to remember to return the value from your recursive call to `$reduce_unwanted_colors` as well:

```
$reduce_unwanted_colors = function (&$arr) use (&$reduce_unwanted_colors)
{
    $rand_key = array_rand($arr);
    if ($arr[$rand_key] == 'blue')
    {
        return $arr;
    }
    else
    {
        unset($arr[$rand_key]);
        return $reduce_unwanted_colors($arr);
    }
};

$arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];
print_r($reduce_unwanted_colors($arr));
```

A word of note, passing `$arr` here by reference, is not needed (Unless you actually want to modify the original array). Personally, I'd recommend against it, as you are actually returning it, so modifying it AND returning it, seems like it can cause unexpected behavior for another developer looking into the application.

You can see some sample outputs <kbd>[here](https://3v4l.org/JknqN)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

That work fine:

```
<?php

$reduce_unwanted_colors = function (&$arr) use (&$reduce_unwanted_colors)
{
$rand_key = array_rand($arr);
if ($arr[$rand_key] == 'blue')
{
    return $arr;
}
else
{

     unset($arr[$rand_key]);
    return $arr;
}
};

$arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];
print_r($reduce_unwanted_colors($arr));

?>
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but this is not what the OP requested. At most, this will remove ONE element from the array. This is not the intended behavior.

Comment: I misunderstood the sorry question.

Comment: It's literally the first sentence.